# function to reallocate growing memory in cuda

Tags: c++, c, arrays, cuda

I am looking for a function to reallocate a CUDA (device-) array, if the data outgrows it's container. the background is sparse data, which I keep in arrays that I initiate at 0 and slowly start to fill.

I start out allocating a given number to start:

in main():

```
int number_of_blocks = 30;
int dyn_cells = number_of_blocks * (BLOCK_WIDTH-4) * (BLOCK_HEIGHT-4);
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc(&h_dev, dyn_cells * sizeof(float)));
```

I then do some calculations and more and more of the blocks in h_dev get used up. If more than half of them are used, I want to make the array bigger. I use this function to do that:

```
void grow_array(float **ptr, int length, int length_new)
{
    float *ptr_new;
    int width = length_new * (BLOCK_WIDTH - 4);
    int height= (BLOCK_HEIGHT- 4);
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc(&ptr_new    , width * height * sizeof(float)));
    //this is the copy kernel
    dim3 threads(BLOCK_WIDTH-4,BLOCK_HEIGHT-4);
    dim3 blocks(length_new);
    copy_kernel<<<blocks,threads>>>(*ptr,ptr_new, length, length_new);

    float *old_ptr;
    old_ptr = *ptr;
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaFree( old_ptr ) );
    *ptr = ptr_new;
}
```

Which I call like this:

```
void memory_manager(int &blocks_available, int blocks_used, float** h_dev)
{
    double ratio = (double)blocks_used/(double)blocks_available;
    if (ratio > 0.5)
    {
        int new_length = 1.5 * blocks_available;
        grow_array(h_dev , blocks_available, new_length);
        (...)
    {
{
```

the copy-kernel looks as follows:

```
__global__ void copy_kernel(float* old_vector, float* new_vector, int old_size, int new_size)
{
    int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int y = threadIdx.y;
    int offset_new = x + y * new_size * (BLOCK_WIDTH-4);
    int offset_old = x + y * old_size * (BLOCK_WIDTH-4);
    if (blockIdx.x < old_size)
    {
        new_vector[offset_new] = old_vector[offset_old];
    }
    else
    {
        new_vector[offset_new] = 42.0f;
    }
}
```

I initially wrote this after a prototype which used malloc and free (non-CUDA) which seemed to work. However this makes my program crash, with the hint to out-of-bounds memory access. I'm pretty sure I am missing some reference/de-reference issue, but can't find where the problem is exactly. any pointers to why this fails?

Comment: You probably need to show *all* the relevant code.  For example, launching a 1-D grid of 2-D threadblocks seems odd.  You can certainly do that, but it gives rise to questions about how you are computing the indexing in your `copy_kernel` which you haven't shown. If it's a device out-of-bounds address you're referring to, it would be good to show the device code.  Can you be more explicit about "make my program crash"?  Does that mean a seg fault, or something else?  Did you try `cuda-memcheck`?  Please show a *complete* app that someone else can compile and run.  Yes, it requires effort.

Comment: [Here's my attempt](http://pastebin.com/8HeBCv4b) at building a code around what you have shown (`grow_array` and `memory_manager`).  It seems to work correctly. If you want help, please provide a *complete* example, just as I have done. Voting to close.

Comment: Dear Mr. Crovella, thank you for taking time to comment. I have included the copy-kernel in question. I haven't added it intially as the out-off-bound error is raised in another kernel that works fine if i work on a "static" size of memory. That lead me to believe there might be an obvious mistake in the memory management part of the code.

Comment: When I plug your `copy_kernel` into my working code, it produces a failure at offset 4096. I'll bet if you attempt to create a simplified example, just as I have done, that you'll discover the problem pretty quickly. Certainly your copy_kernel is suspect to me, but I haven't sorted out your indexing yet.

Comment: I will try to simplify as you suggest an also get your example to run. About the indexing: it's like a 1d array, where each element is the data block of a kernel. So height is block_height (the -4 is because of halo elements). The width is number of blocks * times block_width (again -4).

Comment: Actually I think there is still nothing wrong with the code you have shown, including the copy kernel.  Our indexing is different, but that is just reflecting a different interpretation/ordering of the data (which only became clear when you showed the copy kernel).  Your ordering is valid.  The problem lies in something you haven't shown.

Comment: @Crovella you were right of course, the issue was in another part of the code, which I didn't adapt properly to the new memory management. I am still greatful you looked at my code though, I would have spent a lot more time looking in the wrong places. Would it be appropriate to close this somehow, or should I 'answer' my own question?

Comment: You can answer your own question. I will upvote the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code replacing the pointers with new, bigger pointers apparently was not the reason for the out-of-bounds error, although it triggered it. Found the error in an unrelated Kernel and fixed it. thanks everybody.